# passing value to another page using javascript

Tags: php, javascript

Hello every I want to pass a message from php to JavaScript function and then  redirecting to another page i want to show that message . Plz help me out . here is the sample code

```
Php 
if ($result){
$success = "New Page has been added successfully.";
} else {
$error = "Unable to process at this time.";
}

Java script 

<script type="text/javascript">
window.location="admin.php?page=add_user";
</script>
```

i want this &success message on another page by  using this javascript function . i have tried in this way

```
window.location="admin.php?page=add_user&<?php echo $success?> ";
```

Comment: Can't you just use PHP to post the data to a different page? Why are you trying to forward with JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript"> window.location="test.php?page=add_user&msg='. $msg .'"; </script>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you have spaces in your response, in order for it to be useful in the url you need to url encode it. See php [urlencode](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=what+time+is+it) function. Also, you have to give name to the query string parameter.

Change you JavaScript like this:

```
window.location="admin.php?page=add_user&success=<?php echo urlencode($success); ?>";
```